# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch in package.json

Tags: heroku

```
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://localhost:47627/
2020-03-09T15:02:19.370628+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from /
2020-03-09T15:02:19.370747+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app
2020-03-09T15:02:24.227741+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-03-09T15:02:24.227741+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-03-09T15:02:24.454880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-09T15:02:24.434525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

```
    "heroku-dev": "npm i -dev",
    "wbuild": "webpack --mode production",
    "wstart": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --open --port $PORT",
```

```
web: npm run heroku-dev && npm run wbuild && npm run wstart
```

I looked around the internet, but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema

In your app.json you need a `postdeploy` script.

I assume this is your current `Procfile`:

```
web: npm run heroku-dev && npm run wbuild && npm run wstart
```

Change it to:

```
web: npm run wstart
```

Your `postdeploy` should say `npm run heroku-dev && npm run wbuild`

---

Second approach is to do it via `package.json` (no `app.json` needed).
It is working similarly see the docs here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --open --port $PORT",
  "build": "npm i -dev && webpack --mode production",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm build"
}
```

With `Procfile` being `web: npm start`

---

The problem you have is you are building your project each time when started and it is taking too long for it to bind to the `$PORT`. It should be build once at the very beginning after deployment.

Comment: This comment solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787556/8684435

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue. After debugging found that -
I missed out to bind the app to **'process.env.PORT'**

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do wath you say and I add a new config var on Heroku

key
NODE_ENV

value
production

like in the link:

https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-express-boilerplate/issues/53

It finally work!