# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch - HEROKU ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, hosting

I deployed my Node.js WebApp to heroku but I'm getting this error

```
2021-06-01T09:19:42.615419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-01T09:19:47.259832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-06-01T09:19:51.146182+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running on port 3001.
2021-06-01T09:20:47.916699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to 
bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-06-01T09:20:47.989032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-06-01T09:20:48.124402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-06-01T09:20:48.196055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-01T09:24:45.072782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=positate.herokuapp.com request_id=7e9ec2b1-5685-4c3f-9c29-6c03268b7c82 
fwd="157.51.56.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-01T09:24:46.540443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=positate.herokuapp.com request_id=4ab44a6a-4795-4a4d-b32d-28d796845774 
fwd="157.51.56.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm attaching my app.js here

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");
const timestamp = require("mongoose-timestamp");
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const User = require("./database/models/user_model");

const blogRoute = require("./routes/blogRoute");


mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());



app.use(session({
  secret: "foo",
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URI,
    mongoOptions: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
    collectionName: 'sessions',
    autoRemove: 'native',
  })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/auth/google/positate" || "https://positate.herokuapp.com/auth/google/positate",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      User.findOrCreate(
        {
          googleId: profile.id,
          name: profile.displayName,
          username: profile.emails[0].value,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
        },
        function (err, user) {
          return cb(err, user);
        }
      );
    }
  )
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("Landing");
});

app.use("/", auth);
app.use("/blog", blogRoute);
app.use("/", blogRoute);
app.use("/category", blogRoute);


app.listen(3001 || process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("Server is running.");
});
```

This is my Procfile

```
web: node app.js
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "positate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4",
    "npm": "6.14.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-mongo": "^4.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.11",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose-timestamp": "^0.6.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

I tried various solutions for this error but was not able to solve it. I've been trying to solve this for the past three days.
Kindly help me solve this error
Thank you so much in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a dotenv file with the port inside the project?

Comment: I have it on my local directory and I added the config vars in heroku

Comment: The webapp is running perfectly on my local server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is the way you define the port, it always runs on `3001` which is not possible on Heroku, you need to bind the `$PORT` env variable.
Change your code to check first fi the `process.env.PORT` is defined (it will be on Heroku but on your local dev environment it will default to 3001)

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("Server is running.");
});
```

See [NodeJS on Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error)

Comment: I'm still getting this error, deploying a fastify app.
This is my start script: "start": "fastify start -p process.env.PORT -l info app.js",
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `process.env.PORT` in the Node code (not in the start script)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it drove me mad for plenty of time.

The fix was to configure my webserver to do *BOTH* of the following:

1. automatically pick up port from `process.env.PORT` (also known as the `$PORT` environment variable. Heroku sets this automatically at deployment time.)
2. listen explicitly at the address `0.0.0.0` (`locahost` didn't work!)

---

Turns out Heroku is explaining this in their [help guide](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) already:

> In rarer cases, your app may be using `process.env.PORT`, but may still be failing to bind. This can be caused by the app attempting to bind on `localhost`. Instead, you may need to change this to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the engines from your package.json and try running it again. It looks like there was an issue related to this

[Source](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-classic/issues/3994)

Comment: I tried doing that too, do you think something else might be the problem?

Comment: Another answer above which suggests you need to change the listen bit to process.env.PORT || 3001 might be the way around

Comment: Thank you for replying, the above answer worked