# Heroku - Vite: environment variable is undefined

Tags: vue.js, heroku, environment-variables, vite, dotenv

I have a Vue - Vite application that is served using Nginx in Heroku. It builds and deploys successfully but I'm encountering an issue in the `main.ts` file. Within the file, I'm accessing an env variable that should return a key that I've set in the [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars). However, the variable is returning `undefined` instead of the supposed value. Some additional information:

1. The app is in production mode
2. Env var is correctly named and accessed (`VITE_SOME_VAR` instead of `SOME_VAR`)
3. I don't have a `.env.production` file (I keep seeing this mentioned. I'm not sure if it relates to the issue or not so I'm mentioning it here)
4. This is working locally

Sample code in `main.ts`:

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
  // when adding a debug line, it returns undefined
  clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
})
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Try to pass it through .env to narrow down the problem, also use `VITE_SOME_VAR=` in .env any way, I strongly suspect that only whitelisted variables are read from the env.

Comment: _Try to pass it through .env_ I can't or more accurately I'd rather not. Since the app is deployed from GitHub to Heroku, I don't want to push a `.env` file to the repository

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of research, I finally found a solution. For more context:

I was using the [Container stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) to deploy my app with Docker and [heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) to build the image. The main problem here is that Config Vars are only accessible at [runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#set-build-time-environment-variables). Vite has to access these variables at build stage, not runtime, which is why when the application is deployed, `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_VAR` returns `undefined`.

So the solution was to scrap the docker strategy and rely on Heroku's buildpacks since they basically allow access to env variables at build stage. More info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/416).

For anyone who needs a guide on how to deploy Vite on Heroku, you can refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70355536/17811563). However, I'd honestly just recommend you to deploy to Vercel.