# Deploying Vite react project to Heroku using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, heroku, build, vite

I'm currently facing a challenge while trying to deploy my frontend web application to Heroku. This application is built using React and Vite. Initially, I encountered problems when attempting to build it using the latest Heroku stack (stack 22), which led me to switch back to Heroku stack 20 and utilize the heroku/nodejs buildpack in combination with the Heroku static buildpack from this repository: Heroku Buildpack Static.

This setup worked perfectly for several months, but now, I'm in a situation where I must upgrade to Heroku stack 22, and i was [following the steps provided in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444225/how-do-i-deploy-to-heroku-using-vite), but it didnt work.

It seems that I'm still missing something, as the deployment process itself appears to be successful. However, when I access the deployed app, all I'm presented with is a 404 Not Found error page:
[image]

I tried many different solutions already provided here at SO, to no success.

I removed all previous buildpacks and changed to `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx`. Then i updated my static.json file to this:

```
{
  "root": "./dist",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

If i understood it correctly, it points to my root/dist folder. Then i run the "vite build" command to generate a new dist folder, which contains my built project source code.

Then i created the Procfile file on my root folder and added this line:
`web: bin/start-nginx-solo`

Then i ran `heroku run bash` command to generate my nginx config file, which is:

```
daemon off;
# Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_proxied any; # Heroku router sends Via header

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    # Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        root /dist;

        location = /index.html {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache";
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location / {
            add_header 'Cache-Control' "public, max-age=3600";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a config folder and added this config file inside, named it `nginx.conf.erb`, as instructed here.

My project folder structure looks like this:

[image]

Then i commited and pushed my changes to my github repository, which is connected to Heroku and automatically deploys my project if theres new commits. However, when i open the app, i only get the 404 error.

I *think* that the error is happening because heroku cant find my build folder with my index.html file, however, i already specified the path at static.json and on the nginx config file, so i dont know what else am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Just in case someone else might need some help, those steps are correct, but I had to rebuild my project again with `vite build` and redeploy it. Also, I had the `dist` folder listed in my `.gitignore` file, so I removed it, and everything went well. Stupid mistake.